# Laravel Multidimensional array from database

Tags: arrays, database, laravel

I have a little problem with laravel. this is my database :

[image]

I need a array like this :

```
array(x) {

    [22] array(2) {
            array ( ["id"] => 16, ["name"] => Charente),
            array ( ["id"] => 17, ["name"] => Charent-Maritime),
    }

    [21] array(1) {
            array ( ["id"] => 1, ["name"] => Ain),
     }
     ...
}
```

This is an array, where for each region, we have the list of department belonging to the region.

What is the syntax to get this ?
Actually i use this :

```
    return $this->model
    ->select('id', 'name', 'id_region')->get();
```

But this is not what i want x)

Sorry for my bad english.
And thank you by advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the collection's [`groupBy`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-groupby) method:

```php
return $this->model->all()->groupBy('id_region');
```